# Draggable - How to restrain draggable element from going past the bottom of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, plugins, user-interface

I have an element which is draggable only by the Y-axis. I want it to be able to go past the top of the screen (which it can), but forbid it from going past the bottom of the screen. I read in a jQuery Draggable API about containment, but found no answer as to the question I'm asking, or at least could not understand how to apply it to my case. Here's my code so far:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#elem").draggable({
       axis: "y"
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

Comment: Yes, I know about this, that is how I found out to restrain to the Y-axis. I want to know how to permit it to go off the top of the screen, but not the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a better way but;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#elem").draggable({
       axis: "y",
       drag: function(event, ui) {
            if($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight() > $(window).height()) {
                $(this).offset({"top": $(window).height() - $(this).outerHeight()});
                event.preventDefault();
            }
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the containment option to something that is the height of the page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#elem").draggable({
       containment: "document",
       scroll: false,
       axis: "y"
    });
});
```

Comment: This restrains it from dragging at all per the containment of `document` is the height of the screen. Meaning that it won't go past the top _or_ bottom. I want it to go past the top, just not the bottom. Major Déjà vu.